# ISNULL() not treating 0 value as NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have script for revenue that multiplies invoice quantity to manual price and if manual price is null it will multiply to list price then if both null the value will be 0.

But my problem is I have 0 values on Manual Price so since it's the priority field I get a 0 Revenue which should not be because List price is not 0.

As much as possible I want CASE Statement as my last resort but if there is really no easier way then I'll use it.

```
SELECT INVOICE_QUANTITY * ISNULL(MANUAL_PRICE,ISNULL(LIST_PRICE,0)) as Revenue
```

Comment: You could look at `NULLIF` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx

Comment: Maybe because the value `0` is not NULL. How do you know if the value `0` is not intentional?

Comment: It's odd that you ask to avoid `CASE` statements. This is exactly the right time to use one.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Because there are tons of SP I have to edit so I am looking for a function instead. but I said if there's really no easier way then I'll use case.

Comment: It would be even better to not put 0 in manual_price in the database in the first place. You could enforce this with a check constraint.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @GaryWalker I would look into that. if you could give me a link for that, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx to check `manual_price <> 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) to treat `0` values like `NULL` values:

```
SELECT INVOICE_QUANTITY * COALESCE(NULLIF(MANUAL_PRICE, 0), LIST_PRICE, 0) as Revenue
```

I've also changed the double `ISNULL` functions to a single [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this one

Comment: Thank you so much Zohar! It works. This is what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Then don't use `ISNULL()`.  Use the appropriate logic:

```
SELECT (INVOICE_QUANTITY *
        (CASE WHEN MANUAL_PRICE <> 0 THEN MANUAL_PRICE
              WHEN LIST_PRICE IS NOT NULL THEN LIST_PRICE
              ELSE 0
         END)
       ) as Revenue
```